# Первый первый символ с заглавной, остальные в нижний регистр

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
function mb_ucfirst($string, $enc = 'UTF-8')
{
    $string  = preg_replace(['~[^\s\d/A-Z_a-zЁА-яё-]+~ui', '# +#i', '#^(?:\h*\R)+|\s+$#is'], [null, ' ', null], mb_strtolower(trim($string), $enc));

    return trim(mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $enc), $enc).mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string, $enc), $enc), ' ');
}
print_r(mb_ucfirst('adsad '));
print_r(mb_ucfirst('הראשי'));
```

Давно писал, с русским алфавитом и англ работает на ура. Но что, если это арабский, как заставить работать с арабским и другими языками.

Функция для того, чтобы привести первый символ к верхнему регистру, остальные к нижнему.
Я так понимаю удаляет в регулярке

Как ее привести так, чтобы не удаляла буквы, толком не помню что находим и удаляем...

```
'~[^\s\d/A-Z_a-zЁА-яё-]+~ui' - не помню
'# +#i' - если не ошибаюсь, находим один и более пробелы подряд
'#^(?:\h*\R)+|\s+$#is' - не помню
```

Comment: Так не работает? strtolower($string); ucfirst($string);

Comment: А так - https://3v4l.org/Fg6kO - работает как надо?